# Can We use page breaks in for loops?

Tags: python, html, jinja2, erpnext

I wanted to print barcodes using for loop in python. This is my code:

```
`{%- from "templates/print_formats/standard_macros.html" import add_header -%}

<hr>

{% set a = doc.end %}
{% set count = 0 %}
<div class="row">
{%- for i in range(doc.start,doc.end) -%}

<div class="col-md-4 text-center">
<p style="font-family: Code39AzaleaFont;font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;font-size:30px;">
00000000000000{{ i }}</p>
{% set count = count + 1 %}
{{count}}

<br/>
</div>

{%- endfor -%}
</div>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <p class="strong">

        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        {{ _("Authorized Signatory") }}
    </p>
</div>`
```

The problem is,I wanted to restrict the number of barcodes printed on one sheet of paper to 24.Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Use nested loop where the parent loop will represent pages and child loop will represent number of barcode you want to print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a page break after every 24th barcode using:

```
{% if count % 24 %}<div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>{% endif %}
```

Comment: @LaksHmiSekhar can you share your updated code after incorporating the answer. I am trying to do something similar but I am not sure where should this above code go.

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn't have a really good concept of "paper sheet size". A HTML page has an infinite height and [browser's are notoriously bad a printing HTML in a readable way](http://blog.pdark.de/2010/11/19/printing-web-pages/) (with the notable exception of Opera).

[With CSS 3, three page break properties were defined.](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/)

They might be supported by your browser. If they are, then wrap 24 bar codes in a `<div>` and give that `<div>` a class which tells the browser to break the page afterwards.

If the browser emits an empty page at the end, then you need two classes: One for the first `<div>` without a page break and one for every successive `<div>` and a `page-break-before: always;`

If that doesn't work well, you should look at PDF. PDF allows you place elements exactly on pages with a known, fixed size.